# Problem with the clean target of an external project when running `catkin_make clean`

Tags: cmake, ros, catkin

I have a lot of packages in a repository, some of my packages are installed the following way (snippet of the CMakeLists.txt file of one of my custom ROS packages):

```
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(<PACKAGE_NAME>
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/<SOME_PATH>
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    BUILD_COMMAND $(MAKE)
    INSTALL_COMMAND $(MAKE) DESTDIR=${<PACKAGE>_DESTDIR} install
)
```

This works perfectly when compiling with `catkin_make`, but if I try to run the clean target with `catkin_make clean`, the projects I installed with external are not cleaned. This results in problems when compiling again with `catkin_make`.

Is there any way to solve this issue? I read all the source code for [catkin_make](https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/kinetic-devel/bin/catkin_make) but making the clean target seems to be done entirely by cmake.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the external project be built again and again (and cleaned) as part of your project then please include it using add_subdirectory instead of ExternalProject_Add

If you use add_subdirectory to include it as part of your build system, then when you call catkin_make clean, it will be cleaned